# An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging information follows. When updating modules

Tags: 7, upgrading

I am getting the below error after updating and activate some modules:

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging information follows. Path: /batch?id=323&op=do StatusText: Internal Server Error ResponseText: {"status":true,"percentage":"100","message":"Completed 1 of 1.\u003Cbr /\u003E"}

when I am trying to update the modules and later trying to activate some module, the site crash and I have to restore it with a database.

Please help, I am using Drupal 7.64 version

Comment: In my experience, 500 errors are usually when your web server isn't powerful enough. Can you give PHP some more memory? Are you only installing and updating one module at a time?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers. Unfortunately, it is impossible for us to guess what's going on in your Drupal installation given the above error message. Please check your PHP error logs for more detailed error messages. The stacktracke within these logs will also give you a hint to the cause of the problem. If you still are stuck with it, please re-edit your question and add the most recent error message(s) logged during your update.

Comment: This two links helped me to save the same issue. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2946045 and https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-04-10/php7.2-system.tar_.inc_.patch